# Wrap all controller actions in a begin rescue for error logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rollbar

I've recently set up [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-gem/) for my rails app. It's reporting the errors but not always with context. In order to get context you need to catch the exception and pass in the error

```
begin
  # code...
rescue => e
  Rollbar.error(e)
```

Is there a rails way to generically catch exceptions with context?

Maybe you wrap application controller with something? In Django you can subclass a view...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming all your controllers inherit from ApplicationController, you can use `rescue_from` in your ApplicationController to rescue any errors in any controller.

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    message = "Couldn't find a record."
    redirect_to no_record_url, info: message
  end

end
```

You can have multiple `rescue_from` clauses for different error classes, but note that they're invoked in reverse order, so a generic `rescue_from` should be listed before others...

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from do |exception|
    message = "some unspecified error"
    redirect_to rescue_message_url, info: message
  end

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    message = "Couldn't find a record."
    redirect_to rescue_message_url, info: message
  end

end
```